# Is there any way to fetch more than 1 million records in Google Cloud Spanner?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-beam, google-cloud-spanner

I have spanner tables and using the apache beam is it possible to fetch 1 million records or rows. 
So we are using a secondary index for tables, as it improves the performance.
Spanner table has 4 secondary indexes. A query is not the complicated one, just have one filter condition.
What are the difference b/w SpannerIO and spanner query using statement?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. As long as you are using [ExecuteStreamingSql](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/reference/rpc/google.spanner.v1#google.spanner.v1.Spanner.ExecuteStreamingSql) method (which I believe SpannerIO.read().WithQuery(...) uses under the hood) you should be able to return large result sets in streaming. Use [PartitionQuery](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.instances.databases.sessions/partitionQuery) to improve performance, if the query is partitionable.